# .htaccess "deny from all" doesn't work correctly

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess

I`m trying to configure the .htaccess to deny downloads of a certificate file(.pfx). My website structure is:

```
/app
/resources
   - cert1.pfx
.htaccess
cert2.pfx
```

My htaccess :

```
<Files *.pfx>
    deny from all
</files>
```

In the directory explorer I don't see any of the certificate files.
But when I try to download the following:

**localhost/resources/cert1.pfx**

The certificate file is downloaded... If I try to download certificate located in the root folder:

**localhost/cert2.pfx**

It throw a 403 forbidden error.

I don't understand why one of the certificates is denied and the other one no. Any sense?

Thanks.

Comment: "deny from all" is Apache 2.2 style, it is deprecated in  2.4. Use "Require all denied" instead.

Comment: Do you have anything in your config about `resources/` directory/location? Also, make sure you don't have a `.htaccess` file in `resources/` allowing access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you have one cert downloaded but second not is about Files. Simple *.pfx matches only files in that directory. [Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html) says the following

```
To address files found in a particular part of the filesystem, the <Files> and <Directory> sections can be combined. 
For example, the following configuration will deny access to 

/var/web/dir1/private.html, 
/var/web/dir1/subdir2/private.html, /var/web/dir1/subdir3/private.html, and any other instance of private.html 
found under the /var/web/dir1/ directory.

<Directory "/var/web/dir1">
    <Files "private.html">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Some other hints can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801994/htaccess-deny-files-in-subfolders)
This setup is referring to .conf files, but in .htaccess you may use Location instead. Some more [explanation](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess_for_subdirectories).

Also, I strongly recommend to use "Require" instead of outdated "Allow/Deny".

Comment: The documentation you have linked says: "The directives given within this [the `File`] section will be applied to any object with a basename (last component of filename) matching the specified filename", so it really should work without embedding `Files` into a `Directory` -- not to mention that you can't use `Directory` in `.htaccess`.

Comment: The <Directory> and <Files> directives, along with their regex counterparts, apply directives to parts of the filesystem. Directives enclosed in a <Directory> section apply to the named filesystem directory and all subdirectories of that directory (as well as the files in those directories).

That actually means with no Directory it does not work for subdirectories.

Comment: You can't use Directory in .htaccess, but allowed to use Location.

Comment: Thanks, It works now. I changed the htaccess:
<Files *.pfx>
 Require all denied
</Files>
As you said "deny from all" is deprecated. But the main problem was the cache I think... Now it woks with both versions. Thanks!